# Running external programs as Vim Editor command

Tags: vim

I know I can run the external programs like `ls`, `cat` with `!` . I've been searching around how to create shortcuts to run all these programs as editor commands.

For example, instead of `!ls`, I would like to create `:lsf` . Is there any way to do in Vim ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this:

```
cnoremap lsf !ls
```

Comment: wow. It's like when I type `lsf`, it automatically translated to `!ls` and execute the program ?